# Detect eye ball

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am developing an app which will change the color of your eye. I need some help about detecting eye ball. Currently i have a selector that will be used to reduce ROI. It look like 
this

[image]

So who we can detect eye ball from that selected region. I was thinking about changing the image to grayscale and then detect big black spot from that and then change color of it which will be the next step. i'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: Since you have approximated the positions of eyes, simple edge detection with sobel or other filters in OpenCV could be rough methods, depends on the robustness you desired. It is not easy if you want to be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Your way of thinking about a returning pattern is a good start. I am doing some work on a pattern recognition chair as well, so here is some help for your task:

using a grayscale is a good start btw ;)

There are some "facts" that are always applicable to a non pathologic eye:

- the center is dark
- left and right side surrounding dark ball are almost white (depends on how open the eye is)
- do not forget: you have 2 eyes. link them together in some way (usually they are on an approximately horizontal line)
- there is usually motion in the eyes while the other regions of the picture are relatively calm

Of course I cannot provide any code here, this would blast this whole post, but I hope I could help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response but how we can do it in opencv it will be great if you can refer me to some code resource. Because i have very less familiarity of open-cv library

Comment: I am very sorry, but I do usually work with java, python, matlab or C++. I can't help you with opencv, but surely somebody else can help

Answer (score 1):

I found some link these guys detecting pupil of the eye. May b this will help you . See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137623/Pupil-or-eyeball-detection-and-extraction-from-eye) and [here](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the template matching method from open cv. [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)
this will help you find the eye in most of the cases. 
Another solution would be to convert your image into an edge image with e.g. canny edge detector from opencv. and then search for this pattern with the template matcher. Using the edges makes you independent of the color. Using grayscale images will also facilitate the procedure.